# Open Firefox network before page is opened

Tags: firefox, response, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using Firefox and want to analyses the request/response of a page.

Is there a way to open the Developer tools ([firefox-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools)) - namely "Network" - before entering/opening the page (Automatic opening second tab).

Otherwise it would not be possible to track the traffic correct.

Comment: Because the page was already loaded. Things happened already. Missed everything.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no option/config for doing that (as of v65), but you can do that with `--devtools` flag (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226744), sadly there is some limitations:

1. If you have running Firefox, you should close it or use another profile (*`--no-remote -p profilename`*)
2. Firefox will open dev tools on startup only for first tab and not for all other new tabs.

So, assume you have another profile (let's call it dev), follow this steps:

1. Head to Firefox install location
2. Open up your favorite command-line
3. Use this command: `firefox.exe --devtools --no-remote -p dev --url YOUR_SITE_URL`

*If you don't have/like another profile, you have to close Firefox first*

P.S: Reorder devtools tabs is dead easy, you can do that using drag/drop.

**Update**

Based on your comment, I think all you need is `Persist Logs` option,

- Hit `F12`
- Select `Network` tab
- On first row (*[toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Toolbar)*) you should see `Persist Logs` option, just select that

Now refresh the page, you will logs doesn't deleted anymore.

P.S: `Persist Logs` is available for `Console` tab too.

Comment: The problem with this is that if I want to track the the session, that would not help. eg. the application is opening a new site in a new tab, after server side processing (and removes it from session after first opening) I would not get it.

Comment: So try to open an issue about that on bugzilla

Comment: @PaulEdison the `Persist Logs` option doesn't help?

Comment: how would this help?

Comment: @PaulEdison If selected, console will keep all logs even if you refresh the page, I mean it keeps log history of the tab, so you can see them just like normal behavior

Comment: @PaulEdison I just updated my answer and added more details about `Persist Logs`

Comment: It seems not working for me - it is not simply reloading the page it is completely opening it as a NEW one.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani yout suggestion requires to reload the page, but it would be nice to inspect a popup and this needs the developer tools open before the pop is and Firefox does not have this option

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I asked in the Mozilla forum. Very simple solution: use the Browser Console, deselect all options at the top and select only XHR and Requests. Credits to cor-el!

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1325539